# Загрузка аватарки в приложение

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Как загружать аватарку в приложение, где хранить и как отображать? аватарка прилетает с сервера, через ретрофит. Можно пожалуйста с нуля, по подробнее и профессионально.

Comment: В БД храните, с помощью `Glide` отображайте

Comment: В каком виде аватарка прилетает с сервера? Url или само изображение в байтах?

Comment: приходит просто урл картинки